# Angular 2+ One route handled by two components by condition

Tags: angular

My app has private and public parts.

If user not logged in then he should see landing page with some 'about text', facebook/twitter links and a link to login/register as a root page of application.

If he is logged in - he should get a dashboard page filled with user specific data as a root of whole application.

And surely, it would be nice to have both of these pages handled by one root route "/".

So i wonder, what is the right way to implement it with angular 2+ and native router?

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: isAuthenticated() ? DashboardComponent : LandingPageComponent
}]
```

Comment: you got solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a canActivate guard:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '/', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: LandingPageComponent},
    {path: '/landing', component: LandingPageComponent}
},
```

]

In the guard you can check for a login and reroute to the Landing page.

Comment: Yep, it was the first thing I considered. The thing is - I want both components on root route "/".

Comment: I just don't think that is currently possible with the router. You could submit an issue with a feature request in github: https://github.com/angular/angular

Comment: Or you could get a bit more complex and use the dynamic component loader: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html But I believe this is done with selectors and not with routing.

Comment: hey, @DeborahK you got solution for it?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660263/angular2-conditional-routing