# Angular 4 Route based on condition

Tags: angular

I have a route like below

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: './core/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
      canLoad: [AuthGuard]
    },
  ]},
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: coreRoute.login,
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: NotfoundComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404',
  },
];
```

I have two directories which have dashboard module, say 'core' and 'temp'. I want to check if dashboard module exist in 'temp' then the route should be './core/temp/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' else './core/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'

Is this possible?

Comment: You should take a look at CanActivateGuard.
Or maybe this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660263/angular2-conditional-routing

Comment: is there a way to check whether a module exist in a directory?

Answer (score 0):

If your module does not exist in your Directory, you wont be able to import it to your routing module.