# Angular 5 multiple Conditional Routing : "AuthGuards"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am trying to create conditional routing in angular 5 and i have seen this post and the official milestone page of angular:
[Angular2 conditional routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660263/angular2-conditional-routing).

But i didn't find a way to create multiple conditions based on input variables.
here is my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthServiceService} from './auth-service.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthguardService  implements CanActivate{

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private AuthService:AuthServiceService
    ) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if(this.AuthService.ValidAs("User")!=true){
            this.router.navigate(['pages/login']);
            return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
    }

}
```

My `AuthService.ValidAs()` method takes an argument to determine the type of user to try and validate as rightful to access a route and returns a boolean. i have three types of users, how do i pass extra arguments to the `canActivate` property in my routes in order to use that as argument to my `ValidAs` method.

If there is any other way to create multiple `canActivate` instances without multiplying files, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `data` object to any route like that:

```
...
{
   path:'dashboard',
   component:DashboardComponent,
   canActivate:[
      AuthGuard
   ],
   data:{
      roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_EDITOR', 'OTHER_ROLE'],
      // any other relevant data to make your checks
   }
},
...
```

Then in your AuthGuard you can retrieve the data like:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    ...
    const roles = route.data[ 'roles' ] as Array<string>;

    // Do other checks here
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First is to use `params` or `queryParams`.

```
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  const userType = router.paramMap.get('userType');
}
```

Second is to use the dependency injection.

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private AuthService: AuthServiceService,
  @Inject(CURRENT_USER) user: User,
) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  const userType = this.user.type;
}
```

Comment: If i use the queryparams, that mean the user will see his userType in the url and might be able to tamper with the validation results.

Comment: if i use the second method, where cna i store the UserVariable, that i am injecting ? can you just explain a bit more the second solution