# After the login operation change routes angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-routing

I have a angular application. After logging in I want to change my routing operations according to the role of the user. I want to use this role on routing, similar like this,

login result as below,

```
{
"TOKEN":"tokenhere",
"USERINFO":"userinfor here",
"USERROLE":"1 like admin"
}
```

And I create a `PageService` class in that,

```
export class PageService {
    static getNormalUserRoute() {
        return [
            { path: "", component: MainComponent, data: { state: {} }, canActivate: [NeedAuthGuard] },
            { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, data: { state: {} } },
            //..OthersHere
            { path: "**", component: NotfoundComponent, data: { state: {} }, canActivate: [NeedAuthGuard] },
        ];
    }
    static getAdminUserRoute() {
        return [
            { path: "", component: MainComponent, data: { state: {} }, canActivate: [NeedAuthGuard] },
            { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, data: { state: {} } },
            { path: "management", component: ManagementComponent, data: { state: {} }, canActivate: [NeedAuthGuard] },
            //..Others
            { path: "**", component: NotfoundComponent, data: { state: {} }, canActivate: [NeedAuthGuard] },
        ];
    }
}
```

After then i call this function like this in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = PageService.getNormalUserRoute();
```

I want to change here after user logged application.

Is is possible or any alternative solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49938649/4051471