# Angular 6 routing - setting children route component based on parent route parameters

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following routing configuration in my Angular 6 project.

```
    path: 'chart/:feature',
    component: ChartStateComponent,
    canActivateChild: [ChartGuardService],
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            redirectTo: '/chart/:feature/:id/profile',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {   path: ':id/:tab',
            component: TestOneComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
```

`feature` is param to parent path and it can 4 different values like `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`. Now depending on this param, I need to set the component for `children` path.

For example, if `feature` is set `one`, then set `TestOneComponent` as children component.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
path: 'chart',
component: ChartStateComponent,
canActivateChild: [ChartGuardService],
children: [
    {
        path: 'one/:id',
        redirectTo: 'one/:id/profile',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {   path: 'one/:id/:tab',
        component: TestOneComponent
    },
    {   path: 'two/:id/:tab',
        component: TestTwoComponent
    },
    ...
],
```

Alternatively, you could build a route guard to handle more complex routing. See this question for more information: [Angular2 conditional routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660263/angular2-conditional-routing)

UPDATE

I'm not sure how you could add a conditional based on the parameter ... but you can add a conditional based on a global variable.

**In a "Globals" file:**

```
 export class Globals {
    public static ISADMIN: boolean = false;
 }
```

**In your module route definitions**

```
  {
    path: 'products/:id',
    component: Globals.ISADMIN ?  ProductAdminComponent : ProductDetailComponent
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Though I have solved the issue using Guards. But still curious know is there way to set the components based on parameter?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can use a global variable. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, global variables did worked for me. Thank you.