# Angular2 Route events

Tags: javascript, routes, angular

I'm using Angular2 routing and I need to subscribe to an event when route is changed. (i.e. user clicked on one of the route links). The important thing is that the event should be when the new view HTML is inserted to DOM.

Are there any events like onNavigating and onNavigated, so I can subscribe to?
I've found a couple of examples on stackoverflow and tried to use them (see constructor below), but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouteConfig, Router, RouterOutlet, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@RouteConfig([...])

@Component({
selector: 'app'
})
@View({
directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
template: `
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
<header class="mdl-layout__header">
  <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Test</span>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" [router-link]="['/routelink1']">routelink1</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="mdl-layout__content" style="padding: 20px;">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
</div>
`
})
export class App {
constructor(private router: Router){
      router.subscribe((val) => function(){...}); //here is I need to process HTML
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532979/life-cycle-hooks-in-angular2-router. What do you mean by "I need to process HTML"? What does you prevent from doing what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with having base class for my routing components and it contains routerOnNavigate override.

```
import {OnActivate, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

export class BaseView implements OnActivate {

  routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
     componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  }

}
```